# How can I get the elements and relations in Archi from Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Archi (http://www.archimatetool.com) and I need to count Elements and Relations in a given Model. I try this for elements but I don't know if it's the better option.

```
//Get the objects in the model
for(IDiagramModelObject diagramModelObj: this.getDiagramModel().getChildren()){
   searchElementsRecursively(diagramModelObj, elements);
}

//Recursive function to get the enclosed objects (If an object has objects) 
private void searchElementsRecursively(IDiagramModelObject diagramModelObj, Set<EObject> elements) throws Exception{
  if(diagramModelObj instanceof DiagramModelArchimateObject){
     DiagramModelArchimateObject archimateObject = ((DiagramModelArchimateObject)diagramModelObj);

     for(IDiagramModelObject diagramModelObjChild: archimateObject.getChildren()){
        searchElementsRecursively(diagramModelObjChild, elements);
     }

     elements.add(DiagramModelUtil.getModelElement(diagramModelObj));
  }
```

}

But I don't know how to do the same for relationships? How can I get all relationships that are in the model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late to answer this, and certainly this question would be better in the Archi forum, http://forum.archimatetool.com/index.php?board=2.0

Given an IArchimateModel instance of "model" you can iterate through all the model contents:

```
    for(Iterator<EObject> iter = model.eAllContents(); iter.hasNext();) {
        EObject eObject = iter.next();

        if(eObject instanceof IRelationship) {
            relations.add((IRelationship)eObject);
        }
        else if(eObject instanceof IArchimateElement) {
            elements.add((IArchimateElement)eObject);
        }
    }
```